# Rails 4 - Fields Which are Not a Part of a Model in Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having problem with some attributes which are not a part of my model. I'm trying to design a simple payment page as you can see below, all the fiels are represented in my database, except card_number and card_verification for security reasons.

When I load the page it is throwing an error:

```
undefined method `card_number' for #<Order:0x00000004eddb00>
undefined method `card_verification' for #<Order:0x00000004eddb00>
```

What's wrong with my form?

Thanks.

**The Form:**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order, html:{class: "well"}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>
  <%= f.input :card_type, collection: ["Visa", "MasterCard"] %>
  <%= f.input :card_expires_on %>
  <%= f.input :card_number %>
  <%= f.input :card_verification %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

**order.rb:**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :participation
end
```

**orders_controller.rb:**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:ip_address, :first_name, :last_name, :card_type, :card_expires_on, :user_id, :participation_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: Card number not permitted? ok, got it. So, why not just use html helpers for this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the part that is throwing the error should be this in your form:

```
<%= f.input :card_number %>
<%= f.input :card_verification %>
```

You could try adding:

```
attr_accessor :card_number, :card_verification
```

to your model.

Comment: Isn't attr_accessor depreciated in Rails4? I'm using Rails4, check the title of question.

Comment: `attr_accessor` is Ruby method. Don't confuse it with `attr_accessible`.